# "Uncaught Instance of 'minified:p'" when running Angular Dart webapp

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-dart, bundling-and-minification

When running my Angular Dart webapp, I get the following error on initializing/refreshing the webpage.

```
Uncaught Instance of 'minified:p'
  at Object.b(http://localhost:53322/webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js:372:3)
  at nn.$0(http://localhost:53322/webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js:5460:20)
  at Object.uC(http://localhost:53322/webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js:1276:5)
  at kJ.uH (http://localhost:53322/webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js:1278:7)
  at lK.$1 (http://localhost:53322/webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js:4870:3)
  at vc (http://localhost:53322/webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js:446:17)
  at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (http://localhost:53322/webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js:454:51)
```

I understand it comes from Dart conversion to Javascript and then code minification. I've already tried to uninstall/reinstall Dart.

But do you have any idea of what I have to change in my code to remove this error ?

NB : using `Chrome / dart 2.4 / webdev 2.0.5` (which I cannot upgrade because of other packages that have dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; use `webdev serve` instead of `webdev build` and the exception will be better in the console.

This exception usually occurs after the webapp is built and minified.  There is more than likely a legitimate exception being thrown.  What you should do is run your web app in debug mode by running `webdev serve` instead of just doing a `webdev build`.  Once its in the *development mode* you should see a much more meaningful error in Chrome's debug console.